# Alguem me ajuda a encontrar o erro nesse create?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE PedidoProduto + ProdutoPedido ( 
Quantidade numeric(50),
IDproduto int,
IDpedido int,
FOREIGN KEY(IDproduto) REFERENCES Produto (IDproduto),
FOREIGN KEY(IDpedido) REFERENCES Pedido (IDpedido)
);
```

No erro dá isso:

> Mensagem 102, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 63
>   Sintaxe incorreta próxima a '+'.

A tabela `PedidoProduto` é associativa.

Comment: Você está querendo criar duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: o erro é: `Sintaxe incorreta no +` !

Answer (score 3):

O erro desse CREATE é que não existe a opção + onde está colocando (como o próprio SQL Server está mostrando para você).

Se você estiver tentando criar as duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo crie 2 CREATE separados no seu script, criando primeiro sempre a tabela que irá ter as chaves primárias e depois a tabela que irá ter as FK, ou seja, que irá depender dos dados de outra.